# Why only one of those two scripts works?

Tags: php

I wrote those two scripts with a similar structure but only the first one works on my wordpress site.

The first works registering persons on a database. Since the user finishes the form its normaly entering the data on database.

The only diference to the other its the database query (an UPDATE query).

This one works fine.

```php
    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $hoje       = date('d/m/Y');
            $nome       = $_POST['nome'];
            $email      = $_POST['email'];
            $nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
            $cpf        = $_POST['cpf'];
            $matricula  = $_POST['matricula'];
            $turma      = $_POST['turma'];
            $telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
            $tipo       = $_POST['tipo'];

            if ($tipo == "semestral") {
                $expira = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+6 months'));
            }
            elseif ($tipo == "anual") {
                $expira = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+12 months'));
            }


            $existe = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM fr_socios WHERE matricula='$matricula'");

            if ($existe) {
                echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Matrícula já cadastrada.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/cadastrar-socio';
                    </script>";
            }
            else {
                $query = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `fr_socios` (`datacadastro`, `expira`, `nome`, `email`, `nascimento`, `cpf`, `matricula`, `turma`, `telefone`, `tipo`) VALUES ('$hoje', '$expira', '$nome', '$email', '$nascimento', '$cpf', '$matricula', '$turma', '$telefone', '$tipo')");
                if ($query) {
                    echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Sócio cadastrado.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/cadastrar-socio';
                    </script>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Tente novamente.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/cadastrar-socio';
                    </script>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

This one doesn't work.

```php
    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
            $tipo      = $_POST['tipo'];

            $existe = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM fr_socios WHERE matricula='$matricula'");
            $nome   = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT nome FROM fr_socios WHERE matricula='$matricula'");

            if ($tipo == "semestral") {
                $tipo == "r_semestral";
                $expira = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+6 months'));
            }
            elseif ($tipo == "anual") {
                $tipo == "r_anual";
                $expira = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+12 months'));
            }

            if (!$existe) {
                echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Matrícula não cadastrada.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/renovar-socio';
                    </script>";
            }
            else {
                $renovar = $wpdb->query("UPDATE `fr_socios` SET `tipo` = '$tipo', `expira` = '$expira' WHERE `matricula`='$matricula'");

                if ($renovar) {
                    echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Renovado com sucesso. Nº: $matricula.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/renovar-socio';
                    </script>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "
                    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Erro. Tente novamente.')
                    window.location.href='/area-do-diretor/renovar-socio';
                    </script>";
                }
            }

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: worpress must have some built in query error reporting?

Comment: Both are SQL injectable so you'd be best off parameterizing both. (that also could be your current issue)